# TSQL datetimeofset without seconds

Tags: t-sql

Hi is it possible to use `datetimeoffset` but with seconds and its fraction set to 0? I came up with this solution, but it's looks bit complex. I need to get format like in **dt2** with seconds and after set to 0.
 I feel should be something better. Tx all.

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset = '2018-12-18 23:49:18.8866667 +00:00'  --getdate();
-- select @dt       --2018-12-18 23:49:18.8866667 +00:00

select @dt, 
datepart(ss,@dt) Sec,
datepart(ns,@dt) nSec,
dateadd(ns,-(datepart (ns,@dt)),@dt)  ns0,
dateadd(ss,-(datepart (ss,@dt)),@dt)  ss0,
 dateadd(ss,-(datepart (ss,dateadd(ns,-(datepart (ns,@dt)),@dt))),dateadd(ns,-(datepart (ns,@dt)),@dt))  dt0

--                                dt0
-- 2018-12-18 23:49:00.0000000 +00:00
```

Comment: You solution looks good to me. You could also do `datetimeoffsetfromparts(year(@dt), month(@dt), day(@dt), datepart(hh, @dt), datepart(mi, @dt), 0, 0, datepart(tzoffset, @dt) / 60, datepart(tzoffset, @dt) % 60, 7)`, but that is hardly simpler and requires you to know the `precision` parameter in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of SQL you're using, but here are a couple of options (not sure about performance):

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset = '2018-12-18 23:49:18.8866667 +01:00' 

select 
    @dt as dt
    ,cast(convert(varchar, @dt, 100) as datetimeoffset) as dt0                                          -- pre-sql2012:  if you do not mind casting to varchar first (performance ?)
    ,switchoffset(cast(convert(smalldatetime, @dt) as datetimeoffset), datepart(tzoffset, @dt)) as dt1  -- pre-sql2012:  if the TZ matters 
    ,cast(cast(@dt as smalldatetime) as datetimeoffset) as  dt2                                         -- pre-sql2012:  if the TZ offset does not matter 
    ,cast(format(@dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zzz') as datetimeoffset) as dt3                                 -- sql2012 onwards   (performance ?)
```